# Automatic Brightness Adjuster with Enviromental Light detection for PC?

Tags: windows, linux, automation, cross-platform, display

[Lux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vito.lux) or [Velis](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.velis.auto.brightness) Auto Brightness are Android apps which detect the light levels around you and adjust the screens brightness accordingly. I'd like a Window's 8.1 or Linux version.

I'm aware of Flux for PC, but that changes the color temperature not the brightness and it doesn't detect the ambient light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Calise](http://calise.sourceforge.net/wordpress/) (Linux only) detects light through your webcam and adapts accordingly.